# Occasional segmentation fault in a struct operator function overload

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading, structure

I have a C++ structure defined as follows:

```
typedef struct event{
int id;
string name;
//int arg0;
QByteArray data;

bool operator<(const event& e) const
{
    return id < e.id;
}

bool operator==(const event& e) const
{
    return id == e.id;
}

}Event;
```

I also have a map defined as follows:

```
map<string, set<Event>> mapOfEventsByString;
```

When I want to see if an `Event` is associated to a given string I use this line of code:

```
if(mapOfEventsByString.find(aString)->second.count(event)==1) 
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Problem: Sometimes (and I mean that 9/10 times I can run the entire application with the exact same data set without any problems), I get a segmentation fault here:

```
bool operator<(const event& e) const
{
     return id < e.id; <------- GIVES SEGMENTATION FAULT SOMETIMES
}
```

After many attempts at reproducing the error while debugging, I managed to pinpoint the segfault to that line. In that scenario `e.id` is filled with data and `id` says: "no such value".

Help?
Thank you

Comment: Did you consider (is it possible) that `mapOfEventsByString.find(aString)` may fail (i.e. returning `mapOfEventsByString.end()`)? In this case, the rest has undefined behavior. It could crash at `->` (at best) or even in the following operations.

Comment: Do not that `typedef struct name{...} name;` is a C'ism.  In C++ there is no need for the `typedef`.  You can just have `struct name {...};` and use `name` without qualifying it with `struct` like you would C.

Comment: Yeah, you have to check the return value of map::find before using it. I suspect from your use of "typedef" that you're from C land, and this may be why you've tried to squeeze everything into that one line. I suggest doing it in multiple lines e.g.  <code>auto eventKey = mapOfEventsByString.find(aString); if (eventKey != mapOfEventsByString.end() {if (eventKey->second.count(event)==1) {//do stuff}} </code> Alternatively, use map::get, put your call in a try block and catch out_of_range.

Comment: Apologies for the mental lapse, forgot how to format code in comments.

Comment: @tipaye: There's a "help" link right alongside the comment text entry box. Click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a backtrace we are only guessing, but this is a strong indication that the member `id` doesn't exist, so you're accessing memory you shouldn't.

If the member `id` doesn't exist, then your `operator<` call is broken. Given that it is invoked by the below highlighted part of your code:

```
if(mapOfEventsByString.find(aString)->second.count(event)==1) 
//                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that suggests to me that the below highlighted expression does not assuredly refer to a valid object:

```
if(mapOfEventsByString.find(aString)->second.count(event)==1) 
//                                    ^^^^^^
```

The only way that can happen is if the below highlighted dereference operation is invalid:

```
if(mapOfEventsByString.find(aString)->second.count(event)==1)
//                                  ^^
```

which occurs when the `find` fails, returning `mapOfEventsByString.end()` (which cannot be dereferenced):

```
if(mapOfEventsByString.find(aString)->second.count(event)==1)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think if you actually check for find success you'll see that, 1 out of 10 times, `aString` was not found in `mapOfEventsByString`.

Let's do this, instead:

```
const auto it = mapOfEventsByString.find(aString);
if (it != mapOfEventsByString.end() && it->second.count(event) == 1) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Now you can put a breakpoint in for when `it == mapOfEventsByString.end()` and investigate *why* the find is failing. Good luck!